# Homebrew Installation

Tags: macos, homebrew

so i was trying to install ruby and i heard homebrew was the easiest way to do so. However when i tried to install nothing seemed to happen, heres what i put in the terminal.

```
Last login: Wed Jul 20 20:37:17 on ttys011
Archie-Hyndmans-MacBook-Air:~ moo$ /usr/bin/ruby -e "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/master/install)"
==> This script will install:
/usr/local/bin/brew
/usr/local/Library/...
/usr/local/share/doc/homebrew
/usr/local/share/man/man1/brew.1
/usr/local/share/zsh/site-functions/_brew
/usr/local/etc/bash_completion.d/brew

Press RETURN to continue or any other key to abort
==> Searching online for the Command Line Tools
==> /usr/bin/sudo /usr/bin/touch /tmp/.com.apple.dt.CommandLineTools.installondemand.in-progress
Password:
sh: fork: Resource temporarily unavailable
==> Installing 
==> /usr/bin/sudo /usr/sbin/softwareupdate -i 
Software Update Tool
Copyright 2002-2015 Apple Inc.
```

I am unsure if this means its done or still doing anything or if theres something wrong, apologies if this is a bad question but i have been searching everywhere for an answer.

Comment: Glad you included all your command line fumbling as well!  Thanks!

Comment: I tried to include everything i can in hope that someone could help!

Comment: If you didn't do so already, you need to go to the AppStore and download and install `Xcode`. Then run the following in Terminal `xcode-select --install`

Comment: Thank you so much @MarkSetchell ! :o I downloaded the beta version off the website so when i went to download it it said finding software and now its all fixed. Seriously thank you so much!